# SSIS check list

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Can any one help me getting a SQL Server SSIS developer sample check list(like what kind of things we need to check)

Comment: what r the things to be checked before deploying a package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple items:

1. Make sure your package configurations are modified to pointing to deployment locations rather than development locations, and also that user accounts/ passwords are modified from your dev/test environment to your deployment environment.
2. Check that all user/service accounts and database schemas have been properly set up on your deployment server.
3. Hope for the best, but remember you are working with SSIS.  Don't get frustrated when something petty throws an error.